# When using celery, SQLAlchmey keeps suffering from database connection issues

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, celery

On our dev environment, we started exploring the use of celery. The problem is when a task is launched, SQLAlchemy often has a hard time connecting to our Amazon/AWS RDS instance. This tends to happen after a period of time regardless of what settings I've tried but it's hard to say just how long. Our database is a snapshot of our production database on AWS RDS with all of the same parameters/settings.

The errors include...

`OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')...(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)`

...or...

```
OperationalErrorOperation : MySQL Connection not available.
```

Our engine...

```
engine = sa.create_engine(SA_ENGINE, echo=False, pool_recycle=90, pool_pre_ping=True)
```

(I've tried tons of variations of `pool_recycle`)

On the database side, I've changed the following parameters (though some are extreme, I've tried all sorts of variations)...

```
interactive_timeout = 28800
wait_timeout = 28800
max_heap_table_size = 32000000000
```

I tried wrapping each query to reconnect and this didn't work either. Note this code is taken from a StackOverflow answer on similar topics...

```
def db_execute(conn, query):
    try:
        result = conn.execute(query)
        print(result)
    except sa.exc.OperationalError:  # may need more exceptions here (or trap all)
        conn = engine.connect()  # replace your connection
        result = conn.execute(query)  # and retry
    return result
```

This has been a three day wheel spin and I'm stuck... I hopes someone out there has some insight or guidance?

**UPDATE**

I've completely removed celery from the equation and now it's still randomly dropping out and even in between queries within the same function flow. On the production server, the software is nearly identical now.

Comment: Like this you will replace the local `conn` in the function only. The faulty version down the stack will remain.

Comment: @KlausD.So you're saying to recreate the connection in each function?

Comment: You have a connection in the outer scope, which is faulty. You are passing this into the `db_execute` functions as the local variable `conn`. But this is only a reference to the outer connection object. Now, in case of an exception, you're creating a new connection and replacing the local `conn` reference with a reference to the new object. The original object has not been changed. The moment you `return` you will have the same original faulty connection back. And have the same problem when doing the next query.